# What should I use as unique identifier for an element of a mapped array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have read [somewhere](http://www.robinwieruch.de/the-soundcloud-client-in-react-redux/#comment-2727214072) that one should use this

```
{someArray.map(function (element) {
  return (
    <span key={element.id}>{element.name}</span>
  );
})}
```

instead of this

```
{someArray.map(function (element, key) {
  return (
    <span key={key}>{element.name}</span>
  );
})}
```

Apparently, the reason is that `key` doesn't necessarily preserve the order of the array elements because it is not "tied" to the array element.

As a consequence, apparently, React would need to do more work than when using the element id `element.id` and potentially screw up the order of the rendered elements.

[The docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) seem to be in line with the above:

> In practice, finding a key is not really hard. Most of the time, the
>   element you are going to display already has a unique id.

As someone who uses `key` all the time I am after some evidence that I shouldn't.

Does anyone have an example? Or has anyone benchmarked the two blocks to see if they differ performance-wise?

Answer (score -1):

did some research second approach is good When React reconciles the keyed children, it will ensure that any child with key will be **reordered** (instead of clobbered) or destroyed (instead of reused).
Keys should be stable, predictable, and unique. Unstable keys (like those produced by Math.random()) will cause many nodes to be unnecessarily re-created, which can cause performance degradation and lost state in child components.

Comment: Thanks, that talk is very useful!